# How to use jOOQ converter when using jOOQ to generate SQL without Code-genreation?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jooq

I am using jOOQ to generate mySql queries without generating code and without using jooq to query database.

While I create query like this :

```
String tableName = "sample_table";        
DSLContext create = DSL.using(SQLDialect.MYSQL);
Table<Record> table = DSL.tableByName(tableName);
String sql1 = create.insertInto(table, Arrays.asList(
            DSL.fieldByName("id"),
            DSL.fieldByName("roll_no"),
            DSL.fieldByName("name"),
            DSL.fieldByName("date_enrolled"),
            DSL.fieldByName("sex")
            ))
    .values(
            "1",
            12,
            "Raman",
            new DateTime(),
            Sex.Male
           )
    .getSQL(ParamType.INLINED);
```

The generated query looks like :

```
insert into `sample_table` (`id`, `roll_no`, `name`, `date_enrolled`, `sex`) values ('1', 12, 'Raman', '2016-04-03T03:55:37.940+05:30', 'Male')
```

The datetime value generated here is not accepted by MySQL. I explored and found [jOOQ converter](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/3.2.1/org/jooq/Converter.html) can be used for custom conversions. I could find examples on [how to use conversion while fetching data](http://www.jooq.org/doc/2.6/manual/sql-execution/fetching/data-type-conversion/), but unable to figure out on how to use convertor while querying. How can I use jOOQ Convertor to generate SQL without Code-generation ? Or if there is any better way to generate this query right for sql.

Comment: What type is `DateTime`? Is it `org.joda.time.DateTime`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(I'm assuming in this answer that your `DateTime` type is really `org.joda.time.DateTime`)

#### Using JDBC `Timestamp` instead

The easiest way forward here would be to manually convert the `DateTime` data type to a JDBC `Timestamp`

```
new Timestamp(new DateTime().getMillis());
```

#### Using Converters only occasionally.

Using Converters and data type Bindings is much more tedious when you are not using the code generator. I would personally advise against it.

Still, you can pass a converter indirectly to a bind variable by creating a new [`DataType`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/DataType.html) that contains the converter:

```
// This will be your converter
class DateTimeConverter implements Converter<Timestamp, DateTime> { ... }

// This is how you create a new data type:
public static final DataType<DateTime> DATETIME = 
    SQLDataType.TIMESTAMP.asConvertedDataType(new DateTimeConverter);
```

You can now reuse the above `DATETIME` data type everywhere you construct bind variables, as such:

```
Field<DateTime> value = DSL.val(new DateTime(), DATETIME);
```

And insert that instead.

#### Using Converters regularly.

Much better than wrapping individual bind values all the time explicitly with a `DSL.val()` call, you could declare the individual fields of your table like this:

```
Field<Integer> id = field(name("id"), Integer.class);
Field<Integer> rollNo = field(name("roll_no"), Integer.class);
Field<String> name = field(name("name"), String.class);
Field<DateTime> dateEnrolled = field(name("date_enrolled"), DATETIME);
Field<Object> sex = field(name("sex")); // Don't know what this type is in your code
```

And now, you can use the above fields to insert data using your converter:

```
create.insertInto(table, 
          id, rollNo, name, dateEnrolled, sex)
      .values(
          "1",
          12,
          "Raman",
          new DateTime(),
          Sex.Male)
      .getSQL(ParamType.INLINED);
```

As you can see, after a while of doing this, you will save much time by using the code generator instead...